# Cannot run project anymore with error: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am trying to run hibernate project using existing postgres table as a data source. It worked some time ago but now it seems to have problem with connecting to database and I can't find a reason for this. hibernate.dialect property is set and credentials were not changed since I was able to run server successfully.
The error log looks like

```
#2021-02-17 00:58:53.638  INFO 16849 --- [           main] com.example.trolley.TrolleyApplication   : Starting TrolleyApplication on mikhail-Aspire-E1-571G with PID 16849 (/home/mikhail/Garage/java/trolley/target/classes started by mikhail in /home/mikhail/Garage/java/trolley)
#2021-02-17 00:58:53.644  INFO 16849 --- [           main] com.example.trolley.TrolleyApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
#2021-02-17 00:58:55.129  INFO 16849 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
#2021-02-17 00:58:55.218  INFO 16849 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 80ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
#2021-02-17 00:58:55.613  INFO 16849 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
#2021-02-17 00:58:55.871  INFO 16849 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
#2021-02-17 00:58:55.881  INFO 16849 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
#2021-02-17 00:58:55.882  INFO 16849 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
#2021-02-17 00:58:55.975  INFO 16849 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
#2021-02-17 00:58:55.975  INFO 16849 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2218 ms
#2021-02-17 00:58:56.426  INFO 16849 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.10.Final}
#2021-02-17 00:58:56.525  INFO 16849 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
#2021-02-17 00:58:56.607  WARN 16849 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.c.i.ConnectionProviderInitiator  : HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
#2021-02-17 00:58:56.608  WARN 16849 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The application must supply JDBC connections
#2021-02-17 00:58:56.611  WARN 16849 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'trolleyApplication': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.example.trolley.TrolleyApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
#2021-02-17 00:58:56.635  INFO 16849 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
#2021-02-17 00:58:56.659  INFO 16849 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
#
#Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
#2021-02-17 00:58:56.693 ERROR 16849 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
#
#org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'trolleyApplication': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.example.trolley.TrolleyApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
#   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
#   at com.example.trolley.TrolleyApplication.main(TrolleyApplication.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
#Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.example.trolley.TrolleyApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1155) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1122) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:549) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:717) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:690) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:224) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:359) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   ... 17 common frames omitted
#Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
#   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:616) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:600) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
#   ... 32 common frames omitted
#Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
#   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
#   ... 49 common frames omitted
#
#Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:47427', transport: 'socket'
#
#Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my application.properties file:

```
# Database
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/railways_osm
# ?serverTimezone=UTC&useUnicode=true&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&characterSetResults=utf8&characterEncoding=utf-8
spring.datasource.username = postgres
# TODO: Store the password in a more secure way
spring.datasource.password = postgres
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
# spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

# Templates and front
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true

# Other
server.port=8081
```

the following is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.javatechie</groupId>
    <artifactId>trolley</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>trolley</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MY DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.cr2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SECURITY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- the postgresql driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>8.4-701.jdbc3</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>-->


        <!-- spatial data types -->
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
-->
        <!-- actuator dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!-- add repositories for JTS and Hibernate Spatial and Hibernate (JBoss) -->
    <repositories>
<!--        <repository>
            <id>OSGEO GeoTools repo</id>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
        </repository>-->
<!--        <repository>
            <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
            <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
        </repository>
        &lt;!&ndash; add JBOSS repository for easy access to Hibernate libraries &ndash;&gt;
        <repository>
            <id>JBOSS</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>-->
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem in pom.xml

delete this dependency from pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>8.4-701.jdbc3</version>
    </dependency>
```

try this dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**and check your PostgreSQL server if open or not
and password with username**

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried dependencies you mentioned but still have the same error. I think that postgres server is working properly because I can connect and use it through datagrip in Intellij idea.